# How to set the Listview item size in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have added an adapter to a list view. For some items, the text is lengthy and the item displays only a portion of the text. How do I fix this? Is there a way to set the size of the list view item?

Answer (score 0):

well one solution to that would be to define item layout as a table layout. Then you can set the contents of the column to wrap in the table layout.

This could be a possible layout for your Item to be displayed in the list Activity

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="0"
    >   
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yourContentId"
        />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```